# VBA Match Cell Range to Worksheet Name and copy/paste to respective worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I'm trying to write a macro that matches a cell in the with the sheet name and then pulls data from that sheet and then copies it in the next column with the initial sheet. Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub example() 

 Dim wkSht As Worksheet

  For Each wkSht In Sheets

    For Each Cell In Sheets("Reporting").Range("B2:B200")

        If Cell.Value = wkSht.Name Then

            On Error Resume Next

            wkSht.Range("D15").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Reporting").Range("c2:c36")

        End If

    Next Cell

 Next wkSht

End Sub
```

I want to do that for the whole column but I don't know the code for copying it in the next column over. Basically, it would match the `Cell (B2)` with the sheet tab name and then pull from the same cell in that respective tab and then copy to the next `column (C2)`. And I would do that for `b3`, `b4`, `b5`, till `b200`. Thanks!

Comment: why are you only copying one cell from `D15`?

Comment: Basically it's pulling from a set form, so everytime it looks up the tab name, it will always pull from D15 of that tab

Answer (score 0):

I think I have understood your question. You would need a helper variable to increment as you copy data into a new column.

Code,

```
Sub example()

  Dim wkSht As Worksheet
  Dim i As Long

    i = 3
    For Each wkSht In Sheets

        For Each Cell In Sheets("Reporting").Range("B2:B200")

            If Cell = wkSht.Name Then

                On Error Resume Next
                Sheets("Reporting").Cells(2, i).Resize(35).Value = wkSht.Range("D15").Value
                i = i + 1

            End If

        Next Cell

    Next wkSht

End Sub
```

The use of the `long` variable `i` will allow you to store the position of the next avaliable column to enter data into.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Offset()` to specify a cell with a position relative to the cell in ColB:

```
Sub example() 

 Dim wkSht As Worksheet

  For Each wkSht In Sheets

    For Each Cell In Sheets("Reporting").Range("B2:B200")

        If Cell.Value = wkSht.Name Then

            wkSht.Range("D15").Copy Destination:=Cell.Offset(0,1)

        End If

    Next Cell

 Next wkSht

End Sub
```